# Is there a generation where the games stop giving suggested names for the player?

Tags: pokemon-series

Pokemon Blue had suggested names for Blue, which were [Blue, Gray, and John](https://youtu.be/u0aRVjtjmB4?t=154)

Lyra had about 20 [Optional suggested names](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lyra_(game)#Optional_names).

But is there a point where that stopped? Or are the suggested names for later protagonists just not well documented?

Comment: By "just only give a default name", do you mean that your only option for the player name is just, say, "Gloria" — or a choice between "Gloria" and a custom name?  None of the main series games do that.  Starting at some point (maybe Black & White?), you just enter a custom name without being given any built-in options.

Comment: @jwodder - Yes, exactly what you thought I meant. So if there's no true default name, I'll refine my question. I guess the Default / canon names are whatever they are when they're an NPC.

Comment: I'd like to check, but with DS titles it's hard to find YT videos including both screens